# Searching for a story about a Team of Explorers Trapped with Large Alien Animal

Tags: story-identification, animals

The story I'm trying to recall had the explorers stranded on the surface of some planet. I recall that there was a body of water, and a large alien creature which had a large, globular, transparent body with a nucleus giving it the appearance of some sort of cyclops. The creature would grab anything/one that disrupted its environment.

Generally, it was a hard-science escape puzzle story.

Comment: Roughly when did you read this? Was it a full-length book, or a short story? Was it part of a collection, in an anthology, or did you read it somewhere else?

Comment: I can't nail down the exact decade, but I was quite a bit younger at the time, so say a few decades ago. It was a story, in an anthology. I think it may have been themed on encounters with alien wildlife.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your description reminds me of a story I read in The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction called [Polyphemus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphemus_%28book%29) by Michael Shea.  It got the cover of that issue.

[image]

<s>I don't remember much about it, but</s> your brief description made me think of it, and the cover illustration makes it seem like it could match.

The story has been anthologized [a few times](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49634). In fact, when I looked at that link, I realized I have the story in *The 1982 Annual World's Best SF*, so I re-read it.  Now I'm a little more confident in the identification.  The "body of water" you mention is a lake inside a volcanic crater.

> It was a titanic eye - a transparent orb of gold, intricately veined
> within, the pupil a scarlet rhomboid into which five sand-hogs could
> have been driven abreast.  Deep in the yellow ichor, black shapes
> moved, whole constellations of them swarming through the kelp-like
> jungle of veins, while outside the globe, round its base, a collar of
> huge tongue-like tentacles stirred, stretched, and licked the air.

Comment: Well done! This is the story exactly! I was going to add remembered details about the 'black shapes' moving inside the sphere, as well as a scene where they directed a sand hog towards the sphere with a 'dummy' made of an inflated spacesuit, in an attempt to distract it. The other funny factor was that I was certain the author was Michael *someone*, but couldn't recall who. I think this whole thing was triggered by a recent resurgence of publication by Michael Swanwick, for what it's worth.

Comment: Yes, marked as accepted. Thank you so much, I was wracking my brain!

Comment: Looking at some pictures of used paperbacks, the collection Polyphemus was not where I read it. I too read it in the DAW books World's Best.

Comment: I just looked for the Shea collection The Autopsy on abebooks.com....it was $300...gonna have to skip that one.

Comment: Yeah. I just ordered a used copy of the DAW anthology for $4.13 shipping included. Polyphemus started at $5, and jumped to $145 by the third choice!

Comment: I think the first question I ever answered on this site was about The Autopsy.  Shea didn't write much but they were memorable stories.